# Why is JSON.stringify needed to retain an object's value when importing it from node.js into an EJS template?

Tags: node.js, ejs

**Environment:** Node.js, Express, EJS

When `JSON.stringify()` is used to process objects passed from `node.js` to an `EJS` template the objects retain their original values.  Although it works I find this result unexpected.  `JSON.stringify` turns objects into strings.  Why does this appear to work in reverse in this instance?

**In the Node.js file:**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    let myArray = [1, 5];

    let myObject = {
        cats: 2,
        dogs: 0
    }

    res.render('index', { myArray, myObject });

})
```

**EJS:**

```
<script>
    let importedArray = <%- JSON.stringify(myArray) %>;
    let importedObject = <%- JSON.stringify(myObject) %>;
</script>
```

**Rendered version in browser:**

Although I find this result unexpected it works perfectly fine.

```
<script>
    let importedArray = [1,5];
    let importedObject = {"cats":2,"dogs":0};
</script>
```

**Rendered after both `JSON.stringify()` are removed in EJS file:**

The values are lost and the browser throws an error.  I would have thought the unescaped output tag `<%-` would be enough but it's not.

```
<script>
    let importedArray = 1,5;
    let importedObject = [object Object];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you're trying to specify the source code for a script that will live inside a `<script>` tag inside a web page, you need to generate RAW Javascript source code that will make your object in the web page.

So, you need some method of turning your live server-side Javascript object back into Javascript source code that describes the same object.  `JSON.stringify()` is one such way to generate that Javascript source.

If you don't use something like `JSON.stringify()` and just pass your actual Javascript object, the EJS will see that it's not a string and it will call `obj.toString()` on it to try to get a string representation of it.  Unfortunately, the implemention of `.toString()` for a Javascript object just generates `"[object Object]"` which is completely useless in an EJS template.  So, you can't do it that way - you have to manually generate the correct Javascript source code string.  And, `JSON.stringify()` is one such way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

because ejs only render string text, and when use toString on a json, it will get '[object Object]' instead of your real content